# How can I rotate an image in a .qmd file using RStudio?

Tags: rstudio, figure, quarto

I did not manage to get a 180° rotation of a picture.

```
---
title: "Title"
date: 2022-09-12
format: pdf
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

# Figures

![blabla](images/IMG_4722-04.jpeg){style="rotate(180deg)" fig-alt="blabla" width="100%"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to rotate an image in a Markdown file using an inline style, but Markdown does not support inline styles for images. You can use HTML syntax to achieve the image rotation.

```markdown
<img src="images/IMG_4722-04.jpeg" style="transform: rotate(180deg);" alt="blabla" width="100%">
```

Comment: Thank you @nischal sharma. I tried but it did not work unfortunately. My rendered PDF does now contain no pictures at all.

Comment: @layal It working completely fine for me.... i dont know why it is not working for you. Just make sure that the file path and the file format are correct. is the screen completely blank for you? or do you see inverted "blabla" the the bottom corner of your screen?

Comment: the screen is blank. Only the title, the date, the header "Pictures" and the page number appear. All paths are ok.

Comment: No email, thanks. I will figure this out. Thank you for your help.